# Preferred method of error handling method

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a file based hash table thing that can run into various filesystem or user errors. Initially I created all the data functions as bools like

```
bool add(int key, int value)
bool get(int key, int &value)
```

and so on where the input/output would go through the parameters and the success/fail would come as the function result.

Then I had some mmf wrapper classes I needed to fool-proof for the same project and I realized that they can fail at the constructor in which case returning a bool is not really an option so I added a bunch of

```
if (!somethingthatindicatesfail) throw std::exception("description here");
```

to them.

So now i have something that throws exceptions inside something that returns a bool and then there is system error codes that I also need to include in the error log.

Its a mess.. I'm going to rewrite all of the fail scenario logic but before I do, what is your preferred error handling/conveying method?

The end result I'm imagining is a module that doesn't crash but logs the errors, prevents further damage to the data and advises the user to shut it down.

Comment: _'and advises the user to shut it down'_ As from my experience, such won't help. When there are unrecoverable errors, crash the program. Do not accept any user action from such point any more, this might call fore even more damage and unpredictable situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already pointed out, you can't use return codes from constructors. So, if you want a single method that works for all the code, your only real choice is exception handling.

Note, however, that in some cases, it's preferable to just abort instead. In particular, exceptions will attempt to unwind the stack, but if the situation is dire enough, it's possible that could cause further damage, and aborting (existing without unwinding the stack) is a better option.

For that case, it can make sense to have (for example) a separate watch-dog that logs the problem and re-starts the program when/if it crashes. Being a separate process, it can continue and execute reasonably even if the program itself is bollixed up to the point that its only reasonable choice is to abort.